# Are there testosterone receptors in female mammary tissue?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, endocrinology, sexual-dimorphism

Does female mammary tissue have receptors for testosterone hormones?

Do male hormones influence female mammary glands, as female hormones influenced the male mammary tissue, such as in [gynecomastia](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/gynecomastia/basics/definition/con-20028710)?

Answer (score 4):

The female mammary gland tissue contains androgen receptors (testosterone is an androgen). So this tissue is sensitive to androgens, and they inhibit the estrogen-induced proliferation. The inactivation of the androgen receptor on the other hand leads to an accelerated growth of the pubertal mammary gland and to the upregulation of estrogen receptor α expression in female mice. See references 1-3.

And the androgen receptor also seem very important in the formation of the nipples, as testosterone here directs apoptosis in the forming breast tissue. Mice without a functioning androgen receptor were born without nipples. See reference 4 and 5 for details.

To answer your question shortly: Yes, androgen hormones (among them testosterone) have a profound influence on the female mammary gland.

References:

1. [Testosterone inhibits estrogen-induced mammary epithelial
   proliferation and suppresses estrogen receptor expression.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10973921)
2. [Minireview: The Androgen Receptor in Breast Tissues: Growth
   Inhibitor, Tumor Suppressor, Oncogene](http://press.endocrine.org/doi/full/10.1210/me.2012-1107)
3. [Androgen receptor inactivation resulted in acceleration in pubertal
   mammary gland growth, upregulation of ERα expression, and
   Wnt/β-catenin signaling in female mice.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25076121)
4. [Hormone Action in the Mammary Gland](http://cshperspectives.cshlp.org/content/2/12/a003178.full)
5. [Specificity of tissue interaction and origin of mesenchymal cells in
   the androgen response of the embryonic mammary gland.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7357614?dopt=Abstract)

Comment: @esi72 
If this answer [addressed your problem](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-wo‌​rk) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered.